# jQuery Document Ready Hover Detection

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that adds a 'selected' calss and displays a dropDown div upon the user hovering over one of the list items.

When the page is loaded, I'm trying to detect if any of the list items have the mouse over them, and if not, activate the hover event.

For some reason, this code doesn't work. It looks like "if($('li').not(':hover')) {" is to blame.

Can anyone hightlight where I'm going wrong, and point me in the right direction?

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">

ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

li
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.dropDown
{
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
}

.selected
{
  background: red;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('li').not(':hover')) {
        $('li').hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $(this).find('.dropDown').show();
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            $(this).find('.dropDown').hide();
        })
    }
})

</script>


<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">Menu Item One</a>
        <div class="dropDown"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">Menu Item Two</a>
        <div class="dropDown"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">Menu Item Three</a>
        <div class="dropDown"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">Menu Item Four</a>
        <div class="dropDown"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">Menu Item Five</a>
        <div class="dropDown"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When document is ready, do you want to set one of the menu items to be active if nothing is hovered? Or do you want just define the behaviour of menu items on hover? If second, you don't need that check at all.
Also, 'hover()' doesn't work since JQuery version 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is you can't just check if a jQuery object exists or not. Even when there are no elements matching the selector and filter an object is still created.

You need to test if the array of elements found within the object have `length`. No length means no elements matched

```
if($('li').not(':hover').length)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue still remains if its changed to 'if($('li').not(':hover').length) {' ?

Comment: I don't believe that jQuery has a `:hover` selector. Also you aren't making attempt to trigger any events. Your hover handler shouldn't be wrapped in any conditional

Comment: Onload I'm trying to see if there is any menu items hovered. If there isn't, then it should allow you to hover.

Comment: will probably have to check position of mouse and all menu items and see if mouse is in bounds of any of the elements and adjust classes accordingly. No mouseeneter event will be fired if mouse is in static position